# Creating a Photoshop Like Black and White Filter for MATLAB Figures

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot, photoshop

Creating grayscale images from Matlab figures can be a big pain because you have to scale your colormaps and color limits just right so that the gray colormap picks up all the details. I've realized that Photoshop is very, very good for doing this. You load in an image and use the black and white filter, and then change the levels of reds, greens, blues, etc. to suit the details of your image. See below for an example

[Example Image - Photoshop Black & White Filter Applied on MATLAB Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34W2d.png)

I think it would be extremely useful to have a function that one can call that takes in the same inputs as Photoshop requires. This function might be of the form

```
  function bwfilter(h, C)
```

where C is a matrix that takes in the input of red, green, cyan, etc. percentages, and h is a figure handle. Upon running the function, the figure is converted to black and white and either kept as Matlab's .fig format, or if not possible, exported as a png, pdf, etc. perhaps using the excellent [export_fig function by Oliver Woodford](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-exportfig).

I'm not sure how to go about this. Can someone advise? Of course, if anybody wants to step to the challenge...

Comment: You may use this implementation of Photoshop's Black and White Filter - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55185251.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
function StackExchange_rgb2gray_rygcbm
% http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083685/creating-a-photoshop-like-black-and-white-filter-for-matlab-figures

    function imGray = rgb2gray_rygcbm(imgRGB,Coefficients)
        %
        % imgRGB        source RGB image
        %
        % Coefficients  vector of color coefficients
        %                   [red yellow green cyan blue magenta]
        %
        %                   0.0 means that the corresponding color
        %                           will not contribute to resulting gray image
        %
        %                   1.0 means that the corresponding color intensity
        %                           will be unchanged on resulting gray image
        %
        %                   values higher than 1.0 might work but only if product
        %                           (Maximal_Color_Intensity * Color_Coefficient) <= 1
        %
        %                   rgb2gray_rygcbm(imgRGB,[1 1 1 1 1 1]) is equivalent to rgb2gray(imgRGB)
        %
        % Author: Andriy Nych
        %   Date: 2013/04/19
        %

        % we check what we are fed with
        if length(Coefficients)~=6
            error('Second argument MUST be 6 elements long!');
        end
        % extract color information from image
        imgHSV  = rgb2hsv(imgRGB);
        imgH    = imgHSV(:,:,1);
        imgS    = imgHSV(:,:,2);
        imgV    = imgHSV(:,:,3);
        % prepare some small stuff
        Coefficients(Coefficients<0) = 0;
        Coefficients    = [ Coefficients(:)' Coefficients(1) ];
        rygcbm          = linspace(0,1,7);
        % cook some "magic"
        imgHf           = imgH;
        for kk=1:6
            iidx            = (rygcbm(kk)<=imgH) & (imgH<rygcbm(kk+1));
            tx              = imgH(iidx);
            ty              = Coefficients(kk) + sin( (tx-rygcbm(kk))/(rygcbm(kk+1)-rygcbm(kk)) * pi/2 ).^2 * (Coefficients(kk+1)-Coefficients(kk));
            imgHf(iidx)     = ty;
        end
        % apply the "magic"
        imgV2   = imgV .* imgHf;
        imgN    = hsv2rgb( cat(3,imgH,imgS,imgV2) );
        % and this is it
        imGray  = rgb2gray(imgN);
    end

% Now we shall test the code

% First we generate an RGB image
figure;
surf(peaks(64));
colormap(hsv(256));
F = getframe(gcf);
close(gcf);
imgRGB = F.cdata;

% Now we create simple GUI and display the results
mm = 0.2;
figure('Color','w', 'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0 0 1 1]+[+1 +1 -2 -2]*mm);
imgGray = rgb2gray(imgRGB);
a1 = subplot(1,2,1);    h0 = imshow(imgRGB);    axis on;    title('Original image');
a2 = subplot(1,2,2);    h1 = imshow(imgGray);   axis on;    title('rgb2gray');
mm = 0.05;
set(a1, 'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0.0 0.0 0.5 1.0]+[+1 +1 -2 -2]*mm );
set(a2, 'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0.5 0.0 0.5 1.0]+[+1 +1 -2 -2]*mm );
pause(1);

% we convert the original image for different combination of the coefficients
Coeffs = [0 0 0 0 0 0];
NSteps = 10;
for ic=1:6
    % we'll change one coefficient at a time

    for k=0:NSteps
        % we modify the coefficient
        Coeffs(ic) = k/NSteps;
        % and use them for image conversion
        imgGray = rgb2gray_rygcbm(imgRGB,Coeffs);

        % now we show the result
        axis(a2);
        imshow(imgGray);   axis on;
        %set(h1,'CData',imgGray);
        title(a2, sprintf('r:%5.2f y:%5.2f g:%5.2f c:%5.2f b:%5.2f m:%5.2f',Coeffs) );

        drawnow;
        pause(.1);
    end
end

end
```

Comment: Thank you for your fantastic effort. The thing I'm trying to figure out is how does your Coefficients vector compare with Photoshop's Coefficient values (which for RYGCBM values ranges from -200% to 200%). In asking this question, I realize that I actually have no idea how Photoshop does the conversion. This would make deciding the correct values easy (can always open up the image in Photoshop and find the right values). If not, then I imagine a GUI with sliders would be a very useful feature to go with your code. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have photoshop to check its algorithm. For me a coefficient from 0.0 to 1.0 (or from 0 to 100%) means that you should multiply the color intensity by that factor. If you use coefficient >1 (>100%) I think that the color intensity will be "amplified". But I have no idea how to interpret negative coefficients from photoshop. May be they used log-scale? Or may be lower coefficient have "wider" effective range? For example, setting 0.0 for yellow will "erase" just yellow color, but setting -1 may erase yellow color and some colors towards red and green as well.